# Configure a docker container as environment variable in another container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, containers, octave

I have a docker container that executes octave-cli, what I want is to have that executable as an environmental variable in another container so that I could run it using a python script.

I am using oct2py library in my python script which requires an environmental variable with octave executable. There is no PPA with the latest version of octave that is required hence I found an octave docker image(mtmiller/octave) that works well with my .m files. Now I want it to be available in my python container so that the script works.

### Example octave script

```
function hello()
    printf("hello,world!")
endfunction
```

### Python script

```
from oct2py import octave
octave.add('path/to/octavefile')
octave.hello()
```

### Output

`hello,world!`

Requirement to run above python script

> You must have GNU Octave installed and in your PATH environment variable. Alternatively, you can set an OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE or OCTAVE environment variable that points to octave-cli executable itself.

Now, I have mtmiller/octave that executes octave. How to set it in the PATH of the python container?

Comment: `docker run docker-image command`

Comment: are you using a docker-compose file,     you can use environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker    ,also give an example of what you are trying

Comment: @JoranBeasley Docker inside docker? Is there a way to treat both the containers as separate?

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham If I use the docker-compose, will I be able to run the octave container from the python container since both of them are on the same network?

Comment: can you elaborate your question and put some code or pic or the variable that you are passing to the program.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham I did, check the edit. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to install python int the Octave container and the try you problem, so that it becomes single container.

Comment: no there is no way to accomplish what you ask, based on the example provided... but i suspect there is some package that allows you to serve your functions as urls ... then you could just use a restlike api I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect octave offers a web api package thing .... but i have no idea about it but you could run a lightweight flask api server on your octave server

## octave docker image

**octave-server.py**

```
import flask
import subprocess
from oct2py import octave
octave.add('path/to/octavefile')

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route("hello.m")
def hello_fn_call():
    users_name = flask.request.args.get("name")
    return json.dumps(octave.hello(users_name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # you should really serve this with nginx + gunicorn or something
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## python docker image

**octave_rest.py**

```
import requests
def say_hello(username):
    return requests.get("http://other-image:5000/hello.m",{"name":username}).json()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(say_hello("BOB"))
    # something like "Hello, Bob"
```

if you really want to print strings in your octave program you will need to capture the standard out, this decorator should help (of coarse you can do it all manually also)

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout # py3.4+ only
import io

...

@app.route("hello.m")
def hello_fn_call():
    users_name = flask.request.args.get("name")    
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        hello(users_name) # capture stdout
    return json.dumps(f.getvalue())
```